# Reading materials for banach stone theorem

Tags: reference-request

I am interested In the banach stone theorem. Currently I am still in my undergraduate,. Recently I have read up the 3 fundamental theorems in functional analysis, Hahn banach theorem, principle of uniform boundedness and open mapping theorem. May I know what should I read so that I can understand the banach stone theorem further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following book seems like it would be a good fit for you:

George Finlay Simmons, [**Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1575242389), McGraw-Hill Book Company, 1963, xvi + 372 pages.